# Efficiently re-stacking a numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, transform

I have a problem with re-stacking numpy ndarrays in a certain manner. I want to re-stack the inner 2D matrices so that the columns are adjacent to each other.  For example, if this is my input:

```
>>> k.shape
(2, 3, 3, 2)
>>> k
array([[[[ 7.,  6.],
         [ 7.,  5.],
         [ 5.,  5.]],

        [[ 2.,  7.],
         [ 5.,  2.],
         [ 7.,  1.]],

        [[ 9.,  1.],
         [ 7.,  1.],
         [ 2.,  6.]]],


       [[[ 5.,  8.],
         [ 9.,  6.],
         [ 3.,  7.]],

        [[ 8.,  2.],
         [ 2.,  8.],
         [ 4.,  4.]],

        [[ 8.,  9.],
         [ 5.,  9.],
         [ 2.,  4.]]]], dtype=float32)
```

I DO know I need to know `np.hstack`, I just don't know how to do it well. Here's currently how I'm doing it, and this is what I want it to look like:

```
>>> np.array([np.hstack(j) for j in k])
array([[[ 7.,  6.,  2.,  7.,  9.,  1.],
    [ 7.,  5.,  5.,  2.,  7.,  1.],
    [ 5.,  5.,  7.,  1.,  2.,  6.]],

   [[ 5.,  8.,  8.,  2.,  8.,  9.],
    [ 9.,  6.,  2.,  8.,  5.,  9.],
    [ 3.,  7.,  4.,  4.,  2.,  4.]]], dtype=float32)
```

You can imagine it like this: I have 2 images of dimension 3x2 and each image has 3 channels. I want to horizontally stack all the channels of EACH image next to each other.

I apologise if the example is a little weird, but the data I am working with does not get any simpler than this.

List comprehension in python is really slow. Is there a faster way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Just reshape with that desired shape.

Comment: Reshaping does not re-stack your columns horizontally, so that is out of the question...

Comment: @Divakar, sorry, my example was terrible as it did not convey what I wanted to do. I hope it makes more sense now. I am trying to restack columns in a certain manner.

Comment: could you seperate what you want the final array to be like and what it currently is  ?

Comment: It is what I want it to be like... but the code I'm using to do that is, I feel, inefficient.

Comment: Probably something like : `arr.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(2,3,-1)`.

Comment: I can't even begin to imagine how that would be a legitimate solution, but it somehow works. I'm dumbfounded. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can permute axes with `np.transpose` and then reshape -

```
arr.transpose(0,2,1,3).reshape(2,3,-1)
```

Comment: Thanks. I felt you never got the credit you deserved for this.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Ah I just noticed your post had the same contents. Too late now I guess.